# Transform sequence into array of sequences

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe where there are 30 observations per unique ID like so:

```
id  time  features
 1     0   [1,2,3]
 1     1   [4,5,6]
..    ..        ..
 1    29   [7,8,9]
 2     0   [0,1,2]
 2     1   [3,4,5]
..    ..        ..
 2    29   [6,7,8]
..    ..        ..
```

What I need to do is create an array of sequences to feed into a keras neural network. So, for example let's say I have the following smaller dataset for one id:

```
id  time  features
 1     0    [1,2,3]
 1     1    [4,5,6]
 1     2    [7,8,9]
```

The desired data format is:

```
[[[1,2,3]
  [0,0,0]
  [0,0,0]],
 [[1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [0,0,0]],
 [[1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]]]
```

I can use the `pad_sequences` function from the keras package to add the [0,0,0] rows so what I really need to be able to do is to create the following array for all ids.

```
[[[1,2,3]],
 [[1,2,3],
  [4,5,6]],
 [[1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]]]
```

The only way I can think to do it is with loops, something like this:

```
x = []
for i in range(10000):
   user = x_train[i]
   arr = []
   for j in range(30):
      arr.append(user[0:j])
   x.append(arr)
```

A loop solution isn't feasible though. I have 904 batches of 10,000 unique ids each with 30 observations. I'm collecting one batch at a time into a numpy array so a numpy solution is fine. A pyspark solution using rdds would be awesome. Something using `map` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a numpy solution that creates the desired output including zeros.
It uses `triu_indices` to create the "cumulative time series structure":

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def time_series(nids, nsteps, features):
    f3d = np.reshape(features, (nids, nsteps, -1))
    f4d = np.zeros((nids, nsteps, nsteps, f3d.shape[-1]), f3d.dtype)
    i, j = np.triu_indices(nsteps)
    f4d[:, j, i, :] = f3d[:, i, :]
    return f4d

nids = 2
nsteps = 4
nfeatures = 3
features = np.random.randint(1, 100, (nids * nsteps, nfeatures))

print('small example', time_series(nids, nsteps, features))

nids = 10000
nsteps = 30
nfeatures = 3
features = np.random.randint(1, 100, (nids * nsteps, nfeatures))

print('time needed for big example {:6.4f} secs'.format(
    timeit(lambda: time_series(nids, nsteps, features), number=10)/10))
```

output:

```
small example [[[[76 53 48]
   [ 0  0  0]
   [ 0  0  0]
   [ 0  0  0]]

  [[76 53 48]
   [46 59 76]
   [ 0  0  0]
   [ 0  0  0]]

  [[76 53 48]
   [46 59 76]
   [62 39 17]
   [ 0  0  0]]

  [[76 53 48]
   [46 59 76]
   [62 39 17]
   [61 90 69]]]


 [[[68 32 20]
   [ 0  0  0]
   [ 0  0  0]
   [ 0  0  0]]

  [[68 32 20]
   [47 11 72]
   [ 0  0  0]
   [ 0  0  0]]

  [[68 32 20]
   [47 11 72]
   [30  3  9]
   [ 0  0  0]]

  [[68 32 20]
   [47 11 72]
   [30  3  9]
   [28 73 78]]]]
time needed for big example 0.2251 secs
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I added a final reshape to the output: x = x.reshape(x.shape[0]*x.shape[1],x.shape[1],x.shape[3]), but this is otherwise exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something along these lines:

```
dict1 = {}

for tuple1 in your_collection:
    if tuple1 ['id'] not in dict1:
    ###if we've never seen the id then add a list of lists of feature lists as entry
        dict1 [tuple1['id']] = [[tuple1['features']]]
    else:
        ##if we've seen this ID then take the previous (n-1) 
        ##list of list of features from the current dictionary       
        ##entry, copy its value to a variable, add the current list of
        ##features to this list of lists and finally append this 
        ##updated list back to the entry (which is essentially     
        ##a 3d matrix). So each entry is a 3d list keyed off by id.
        prev_list = dict1[tuple1['id']][-1][:]
        prev_list.append ( tuple1['features'])
        dict1[tuple1['id']].append (prev_list)
```

This has some poor space complexity but may work if you are dealing with a set of limited size.